# Recovering previous version of .tex file

Tags: compiling, texniccenter

I just did something bad :(

I use the same canvas of files to typeset some exercices. I normaly copy the main body of my last .tex file onto a new empty document and start from there. But this time, for some silly unknown reason, I forgot to copy paste the body into a new empty page, went ahead and deleted the things to be changed and started from the same file.

And I compiled. I try to revert back with CTRL-Z but it seems there is a limit to what you can revert to.

So now I lost one of my file. Is there any way I can find it back, is there some sort of history that is stocked somewhere in those bbl,aux files latex creates. Feel free to re-tag as needed.

Comment: If you do not use any kind of version control system, then there is no help! (For a lot of money you could get someone reading out your harddrive bitwise, but this will not work for newly overread sectors.)

Comment: TeX does not generate backup files, no.  But your editor may have saved backup files so it is worth looking in amongst the files in the directory for one that looks like a backup (it may be hidden - depends on your editor).

Comment: Are you using Windows Vista or later? It has a [previous versions](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/05/21/using-vista-previous-versions-to-restore-files-you-thought-you-d-lost.aspx) feature that may have saved a copy of your file.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Not in TeXnicCenter.

Comment: @andrew I will try the windows 7 restore when i get back home

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that Windows restore made the trick. Thank you @andrew

Comment: I’m happy I could help!